# Wired Connection problem. USB-Ethernet adapter not recognized

Tags: ethernet, wired

My computer is ASUS-UX305FA running Ubuntu 18.04. This laptop does not have an Ethernet port, yet it comes with an Ethernet-to-USB adapter. Unfortunately, I played around with network configurations, and now it does not recognize the adapter. I would like to note that my wireless connection is up and working, also the green light on the adapter is blinking. I searched forums for solutions (for 2 weeks) but none worked.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

did not solve the problem either.

here is my ifconfig output

```
~$ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2582  bytes 241983 (241.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2582  bytes 241983 (241.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.36  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fd01::e51c:b843:a4b0:158d  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::8210:5476:8d04:1f57  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 60:57:18:d0:dc:9d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 364186  bytes 174056594 (174.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 68939  bytes 8962821 (8.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and my network hardware:

```
root@ahadli-UX305FA:/home/ahadli# lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 59
       serial: 60:57:18:d0:dc:9d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-52-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 ip=192.168.0.36 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:48 memory:f7000000-f7001fff
```

I am new to Ubuntu, so if something is missing in my post please notify me.

Thanks in advance !!!

EDIT ON REQUEST OF heynnema:

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:9700 Suyin Corp. Asus Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As you can see, device is not seen.

> ...so tell us what you did

Sorry, I panicked and tried many things which I had no idea about and I do not remember them

EDIT2

I ran Ubuntu from a live USB and here is the output of `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 064e:9700 Suyin Corp. Asus Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade` device is live USB

Comment: It's not showing the adapter at all. re: "I played around with network configurations, and now it does not recognize the adapter."... so tell us what you did. Also, edit your question and show me `lsusb`.

Comment: @heynnema, I editied the post, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: If it's not seen in `lsusb` it's probably defective. Have you tried it on another computer? You can try and boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, retry the `lsusb`, and see if it finds it then.

Comment: @heynnema, The device was working beforehand. I also booted on from USB and added the `lsusb` output

Comment: I don't see the ethernet adapter in that lsusb either, do you? Have you changed any USB settings in your BIOS? Do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and then go to the ASUS web site and look for a newer BIOS. You can also try the apapter on another computer. Report back.

Comment: This BIOS 216 was released just last month... https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-UX305FA/HelpDesk_BIOS/

Comment: BIOS update procedure at https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1008859/

Comment: status please...

Comment: @heynnema, I am sorry. I am o a work trip and will update as soon as possible. Thanks for your patience